# Pods CMS - Get ACT's attached image records by auto-id?

Tags: pods-framework

I have a situation where I can't use usual Pod object and I have Advanced Content Type to deal with. I have a very large record set and I need to build a custom query to fetch the attached image records with main record.

**Example Data:**

Pod Name = coupons

Fields (e.g.) id, name, description, thumbnails(multiple image upload field).

Now, I am querying for example like this:

```
SELECT t.id, t.name FROM `wp_pods_coupons` t
```

How do I get the images attached (thumbnails field) with each coupon?

I  can't do new Pod('coupons').

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, the attachments are stored within a separate table called `wp_podsrel`. Within the table you'll find the `item_id` (coupon id) and the `related_item_id` (attachment id).

Hence you can get all the `related_item_id`'s as a function of the `item_id`:

`SELECT related_item_id FROM wp_podsrel WHERE item_id = $coupon_id`

Your complete query/output may look something like this:

```
// global $wpdb;
$coupon_id = 1; // custom coupon id
$podsrel = $wpdb->prefix . 'podsrel';

$select_coupon_related_item_ids = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT related_item_id FROM $podsrel WHERE item_id = %d AND related_item_id NOT IN ( %d )", $coupon_id, 1 );
$coupon_related_item_ids = $wpdb->get_results( $select_coupon_related_item_ids, OBJECT );

foreach ( $coupon_related_item_ids as $coupon_related_item_id ) :
  $coupon_image_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $coupon_related_item_id->related_item_id );
  var_dump( $coupon_image_url );
endforeach;
```

Make sure that you're only selecting related attachment id's (and not any other related items)! Feel free to expand the query with your custom `field_id` if necessary. Or let me know if you need further help! :)

Comment: I had achieved it using a few joins instead of doing wp_get_attachment_url ultimately. Your answer is perfectly valid. So I am awarding you with the bounty :)

Comment: Also, if you're using http://pods.io/docs/code/pods/ then you can utilize http://pods.io/docs/code/pods/find/ and provide a custom 'select', Pods will automatically join tables as you reference field names too. That would be more future proof, as the podsrel table is about to get a facelift for Pods 3.0 when we add support for code-registered relationship fields, storing field names instead of field IDs.